# Finding cumulative totals with condition and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

Here is my case:

I would like to calculate quantity and price for a given item on any given date.

Prices are calculated using total item quantity and unit price so price changes with respect to item's quantity.

`warehouse_1` states that item was shipped from that warehouse, `warehouse_2` states that item was sent to that warehouse.

Here is my logic:

Fetch deliveries for each item and sum their quantities. (1st CTE)

Find the sum of quantities in both warehouses separately. (2nd CTE)

Calculate final quantity and multiply it by unit price.

Show result which consists of item id, quantity and price.

I wrote a query which does the calculations correctly BUT it gets exponentially slower when data count gets bigger. (Takes 5 seconds on my DB with 6k rows, almost locks DB on my coworker's DB with 21k rows)

How can I optimize this query? I am doing cumulative calculations on 2nd CTE for each row coming from 1st CTE and that needs a rework I believe.

Can I use 
`LAG()`
 function for this use case? I tried that with something like

```
LAG(a.deliveryTotal) over(order by a.updated desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

instead of the CASE block in 2nd CTE but I can't seem to figure out how to use `filter()` or put a condition inside LAG() statement.

Here is my query:

`

```
with deliveriesCTE as (
select
    row_number() over(partition by it.id
order by
    dd.updated asc) as rn,
    sum(dd.quantity) as deliveryTotal,
    dd.updated as updated,
    it.id as item_id,
    d.warehouse_1 as outWH,
    d.warehouse_2 as inWH,
    d.company_code as company
from
    deliveries d
join deliveries_detail dd on
    dd.deliveries_id = d.id
join items it on
    it.id = dd.item_id
where
    ...
group by
    dd.updated,
    it.id,
    d.warehouse_1,
    d.warehouse_2,
    d.company_code
order by
    dd.updated asc),
cumulativeTotalsByUnit as (
select
    distinct on
    (a.item_id) a.rn,
    a.deliveryTotal,
    a.updated,
    a.item_id,
    a.outWH,
    a.inWH,
    a.company,
    case
        when a.rn = 1
        and a.outWH is not null then coalesce(a.deliveryTotal,
        0)
        else (
        select
            coalesce(sum(b.deliveryTotal) filter(
            where b.outWH is not null),
            0)
        from
            deliveriesCTE b
        where
            a.item_id = b.item_id
            and b.rn <= a.rn)
    end as outWHTotal,
    case
        when a.rn = 1
        and a.inWH is not null then coalesce(a.deliveryTotal,
        0)
        else (
        select
            coalesce(sum(b.deliveryTotal) filter(
            where b.inWH is not null),
            0)
        from
            deliveriesCTE b
        where
            a.item_id = b.item_id
            and b.rn <= a.rn)
    end as inWHTotal
from
    deliveriesCTE a
order by
    a.item_id,
    a.updated desc)
select
    resultView.item_id,
    resultView.quantity,
    resultView.price
from
    (
    select
        cumTotals.item_id,
        cumTotals.inWHTotal - cumTotals.outWHTotal as quantity,
        p.price * (cumTotals.inWHTotal - cumTotals.outWHTotal) as price
    from
        prices p
    join cumulativeTotalsByUnit cumTotals on
        cumTotals.item_id = p.item_id ) resultView
where
    resultView.rn = 1;
```

`

Comment: . . Sample data, desired results, and a db fiddle of some sort would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for use without a [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but my guess on what you are trying to do is do a Windowed SUM() calculation as opposed to LAG().  There is documentation [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

The query `cumulativeTotalsByUnit` shouldn't be necessary and is likely quadratic to do the complex self-referential join.

Your delivery CTE should look like:

```
select
    sum(dd.quantity) over (partition by it.id ORDER BY dd.updated asc) as deliveryTotal,
    dd.updated as updated,
    it.id as item_id,
    d.warehouse_1 as outWH,
    d.warehouse_2 as inWH,
    d.company_code as company
from
    deliveries d
join deliveries_detail dd on
    dd.deliveries_id = d.id
join items it on
    it.id = dd.item_id
where
    ...
group by
    dd.updated,
    it.id,
    d.warehouse_1,
    d.warehouse_2,
    d.company_code
order by
    dd.updated asc
```

Comment: That was very helpful, I did not know we could use `sum()`with `over()`. This does not solve the case where one record has data both in `warehouse_1`and `warehouse_2`columns though.

Comment: It would help if you posted a fiddle with some small sample data.  It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you are looking to do with warehouse_1 and warehouse_2 here.  Again guessing but you can just do this query twice with a `union all` in between.  Once for warehouse_1 and once for warehouse_2.

Comment: Thanks for the sum() with over() logic. That helped me find the final solution. Answer accepted! @tarkmeper